# Why do we use different prepositions for Morning and Night

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, usage

Usually we use

> In the morning
>
> At night

Both of them represent time but why do we use different prepositions?

Comment: Have you ever walked in the night?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no more meaningful answer than "because". As with everything else in English, we've been holding a continual election on these uses for some fifteen hundred years and the current winners are *in the morning* and *at night*.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *in the night*, and it is used in some contexts; it's just not idiomatic as the parallel to *in the morning/afternoon*. There is no reason, that's just how it is.

Comment: @AlanCarmack  let me croon at you:  ♪ ♫ *In the still ... of the niiight ...* ♪ ♫

Answer (score -3):

A general rule, is that words that are used with the preposition "the", use "in the", wheras if "the" is not needed, then use "at". Night is the main exception to this rule:

"At night"

"In the night"

Both make sense.

--

For example:

- In the morning
- In the evening
- In the afternoon

and

- At night
- At 2 O' clock
- At lunchtime
- At midday

I don't know the origins or reasons for this, but it probably just developed over time like many language features.

Comment: *At the weekend* is quintessential British English. Also  in general *at the moment*, *at the solstice*, *at the time*, I'm just not finding this answer all that convincing.